# How to avoid the "non-static method referenced from a static context" in java ? really simple

Tags: java, static

When I tried to build this program there's always a error like "**non-static method referenced from a static context**"
I think that because I can use "addto" function in "main". So how can I solve this problem? I need a public arraylist because I have to do the calculations in "addto"

Thx!

```
public class Calculation {  
    ArrayList<int[]> cal = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addto(3,5));
    }

    String addto(int figone, int figtwo){
     ........do the calculations by using arraylist cal
    }
 }
```

Comment: you need an instance of `Calculation` in order to invoke the non-static method `addto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really simple?

```
System.out.println(new Calculation().addto(3,5));
```

or

```
Calculation calculation = new Calculation();
System.out.println(calculation.addto(3,5));
// and use 'calculation' some more ...
```

(You could also add a `static` modifier to the `addto` method declaration, but you would then need to make `cal` static too so the `addto` can use it.  Bad idea.)

---

OK.  So what the compilation method is actually saying is that `addto` is declared as an instance method ... but you are trying to call it without saying *which* instance to use.  In fact, you are trying to call it as if it was a static method.

The "fix" (see above) is to create an instance and call the method on that.

Comment: Yes: `System.out.println(new Calculation().addto(3,5));`.  No: `or add a static modifier to the addto method declaration`.  Not unless you *also* make "cal" static.  Your first suggestion was best :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate a Calculation object inside the main function in order to use Calculation's non-static methods.

Non-static methods only "exist" as members of an object (which you can think of as instances of classes). In order to make this work you'd need to write:

```
System.out.println(new Calculation().addto(3, 5))
```